# send form if all radio button value is true

Tags: jquery

I need to send form if all radio is true(it`s some like yes/no btns),or error if at least one false.
There can be any number of such "Yes/No buttons".
You need to send only if everything is "Yes", if at least 1 is not selected or "No", then do something else
I try this

```
  <form id="someForm">
  <p>1-st group</p>
  <div class="radio-box">
    <div class="radio-success">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" value="conf">
    </div>
    <div class="radio-error">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" value="err" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>2-nd group</p>
  <div class="radio-box">
    <div class="radio-success">
      <input class="form-check-input"  type="radio" name="radio2" value="conf">
    </div>
    <div class="radio-error">
      <input class="form-check-input"  type="radio" name="radio2" value="err">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="test">go!</button>
</form>
```

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();


    $('#someForm')
    .find('.radio-box input')
    .each(function () {

    inputs = $('input[type="radio"]');

    if(inputs.is(':checked') && inputs.val() === 'conf')
    {
        console.log('form send');
    }
    else{
        console.log('some is not checked');
    }

    });

});
```

hope to your help) thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for inputs of type radio that are checked and hold a value of 'err'. If non are checked the size of `find()` will be 0. Also check for yes answers if they match all radio options.

```js
$('#someForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const radio_no_answers = $(this).find('.radio-box input[type="radio"][value="err"]:checked');
  const radio_yes_answers = $(this).find('.radio-box input[type="radio"][value="conf"]:checked');

  if (radio_no_answers.length == 0 && radio_yes_answers.length == 2) {
    console.log('submit');
  } else {
    console.log('err');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="someForm">
  <p>1-st group</p>
  <div class="radio-box">
    <div class="radio-success">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" value="conf">Yes
    </div>
    <div class="radio-error">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" value="err">No
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>2-nd group</p>
  <div class="radio-box">
    <div class="radio-success">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio2" value="conf">Yes
    </div>
    <div class="radio-error">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio2" value="err">No
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">go!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('#someForm').find ('input[type=radio]:not(:checked)').length > 0 )
{
    // handle error
    
}
else
{
     $('#someForm').submit();
}
```